# discover the directory that prevents a file from being read in linux

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, posix

i'm getting a permission denied for a user in a really long path.

```
$ sudo sudo -u user cat /l/o/n/g/path/file
Permission denied
```

i'm pretty sure `path` and `file` have permissions for that user. Is there any easy way to find which of the other directories in `/l/o/n/g` does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will redirect the standard output of `find` to `/dev/null`, and display only the errors (including permission denied) while accessing directories.

```
find . -type d > /dev/null
```

Comment: nice! `find l/ -type d > /dev/null` `find: l/o/n: Permission denied`

Answer (score 3):

If you're okay with limiting the check to user/group/other permissions, use

```
namei -l /l/o/n/g/path/file
```